# Django test runner not respecting unittest.TestCase?

Tags: python, django, functional-testing

For one of my functional tests, I decided to use `unittest.TestCase` instead of a Django test class because it was convenient when cleaning up the test to have direct access to my local development database in the test itself.

Running the test in isolation like so passes as I'd expect:

```sh
$ python manage.py test functional_tests.test_functionality
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
...
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in 0.040s

OK
```

When I try to run all tests at the same time, however, that test specifically errors out, complaining that an object `DoesNotExist`, as though it were using the Django test database:

```sh
$ python manage.py test functional_tests
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
..................E..
======================================================================
ERROR: some_functional_test (functional_tests.test_functionality.FunctionalTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):

... etc.

app.models.Object.DoesNotExist: Object matching query does not exist.

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 21 tests in 0.226s

FAILED (errors=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

I assume the error is with my trying use `Object.objects.latest('created')` when no `Object`s exist in Django's test database.

Is there some way to prevent Django from wrapping all tests in whatever it is about the test runner that prevents my test from accessing an `Object` directly?

Comment: If some additional context is helpful, I'm running functional tests against an API endpoint running on my local server. I'm testing a create method, and I'm trying to avoid having to request DELETE against the endpoint to clean up the test record created by the test. I'm not too concerned with inadvertent data loss since the test is running against a local development database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First a little explanation.

By default when you run `./manage.py test` django test-runner make few steps which involves creating test database (with `test_` prefix to each database name from [app settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#std:setting-DATABASES)), running migration and destroying test database (more details on runner steps could find [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/testing/advanced/#using-different-testing-frameworks))

A good explanation on how django treat test database is described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/testing/overview/#the-test-database)

---

In your case when you run `unittest.TestCase` in isolation **no** test database is created:

```sh
$ python manage.py test functional_tests.test_functionality
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
...
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in 0.040s

OK
```

( ^*no logs about creating test database*)

That's because there were no `django.test.TestCase` called. We can see it from [sources](https://github.com/django/django/blob/61a0ba43cfd4ff66f51a9d73dcd8ed6f6a6d9915/django/test/runner.py#L684) (virgin `unittest.TestCase` doesn't have `databases` property, when django.TestCase [it has](https://github.com/django/django/blob/61a0ba43cfd4ff66f51a9d73dcd8ed6f6a6d9915/django/test/testcases.py#L903))

But when you call whole module (`python manage.py test functional_tests`) looks like you have some `django.test.TestCase` tests in suite so that's why new test database is creating:

```sh
$ python manage.py test functional_tests
Creating test database for alias 'default'...  # <-- THIS ONE
##<skipped for readability>
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

And as you mentioned tests failed because there were no prepared objects for them.

---

Solution

At this point I see few options to solve this.

1. Prepare test data for tests explicitly (by [fixtures](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/testing/tools/#fixture-loading) or manually in tests or setups) so they would be independent from current state of database
2. Explicitly use desired database.

   Run tests with `--keepdb` option (ie `./manage.py test --keepdb`, it will use the existing database and will not destroy it after test runs) and set same [test database name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#test) in app settings as [working database](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#name) (in such case it will not append `test_` prefix for test db)
3. Since you don't want to use `django.TestCase`, so don't use them at all? Replace them with `unittest.TestCase` and it will not create test database

Comment: I appreciate the information. Acknowledging the way Django handles test cases, my question was about how to force a particular test to run outside of the test database/test transactions. In this particular case, my intention was to have the test run against my local database rather than wrapped in a Django transaction.

Comment: Now I think I realised what you asking for. I will update my answer later, thank you for clarifications

Comment: @Derek looks like I figured out with your case, I've totally updated my answer please look at it